# Empty new Cocoa Mac OS X application has 14799 items "still living" when the application has terminated. Are they leaks?

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

When I create a brand new Cocoa (Mac OS X) application using XCode 4.5, turning off "document based" options, and turning on "Automatic reference counting", build, without changing anything, and run using the Profiler using the "Leaks" template, I see 19.76 megs of transitory memory usage, and 2.23 megabytes in "live bytes", including 3132 CFStrings, 1371 CFBasicHash, and a few hundred odd mallocs(), including 192 kb still allocated by CoreGraphics even when the program has terminated.  I see all this in the "Allocations" timeline, but no output in the "Leaks" timeline. I find this disparity confusing.

I would like to know, for example, with a simple Cocoa base reference application, if possible, and if not, then I would like to know what the reference technique is to know which leaks are mine, and which are expected.

Note that with a Foundation-framework linked command line tool, the number of "out of the box leaks" is much simpler, only about 18 mallocs(), totalling 1.06 kb, so it seems that AppKit (Cocoa) is the origin of most of the default "live objects still on the heap at the end of the program, that are somehow, not leaks".

Is there some way to make a simple non-leaking Cocoa base reference application or does the framework itself leak so much (perhaps intentionally) that in fact, this is impossible?

Yes, I am aware of static analysis. Yes, I am aware of garbage collection. If someone wants to not use garbage collection, but only ARC, and wants to really see at runtime what has leaked, can that person do so, without having to ignore 14799 or so leaks in the foundation and frameworks?

**Update:** Source #1 of my own confusion is, as suggested, that I'm looking at the wrong timeline...  However, in my own defense (or to explain my confusion), I have always considered any object which is still allocated on the heap at the end of program execution as a leak, a rule which is commonly observed in the Pascal (Delphi) and C++ world, and indeed on most non-garbage-collected languages on Linux and Windows. Maybe that's not a "leak" in the Objective-C world at all? Is a "living item" in the memory timeline still "active on the heap", and how is that different from a leak? The fact that my AppController is never told to "dealloc" was surprising to me too, but is "to be expected", I'm told.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those look like objects that are "Created and still living." These are NOT leaks, but simply objects that have not finished their life cycle. Since the application is still running, there will always be a set of objects that are still living, but still have pointers to them.

A leak is an object that still lives, but has no pointers to it. Without a pointer, you cannot return that portion of memory to the OS.

To see actual leaks, look at the Leaks timeline in the upper portion of Instruments. When a leak occurs, you will see a red bar in this timeline. Set the inspection range around this bar to view details about the leak below

[image]

Comment: Why are they "still living" when the application has terminated? Is it because they are "linked" to variable names at the global C scope?

Comment: Good question and I'm not entirely sure why and I'm not finding anything off-hand that explains it. I suspect Instruments may simply be showing the last snapshot it took of the application's memory before it terminated and freed all application memory.

Comment: No object is still living when the application has terminated. All application memory is automatically freed by the OS when the application terminates.

Comment: Note that ObjC does not call destructors or manually free memory on program termination the way C++ does. This is intentional and allows programs to terminate much faster. As I said, the OS will free all the memory automatically in one fast operation.

Comment: So it's idiomatic, for example, that my almost-trivial-Cocoa-app's AppController's dealloc method is never called? Or is that a refcount/cycle? It doesn't show up in the "leaks" timeline, but it is "still alive" whenever the last snapshot was taken for the Allocations timeline.  I wish Allocations really did show everything up until program termination.

Comment: It is intentional that it is rare for the AppController's dealloc to be called. There are very specific cases where it can be called, but they are very unusual and you should not expect it.

Comment: There's an app delegate method that will be called before termination to permit you to clean up anything you need to (file descriptors, network connections, etc.) The specific method escapes me at the moment, but I believe it is applicationWillTerminate:

Comment: You may also be interested in this question relating to other program termination optimizations made by UIKit (though not universal to ObjC): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290039/why-after-executing-pool-drain-it-never-return-back-to-caller/14290087#14290087

Comment: Also see Apple's documentation on OS X's Sudden Termination feature:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW28

Comment: Also, from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW2) and elsewhere in Apple's documentation, there are notes like this: "When an application terminates, objects may not be sent a dealloc message. Because the process’s memory is automatically cleared on exit, it is more efficient simply to allow the operating system to clean up resources than to invoke all the memory management methods."

Comment: Understood... It's a waste of cpu cycles to tear down precisely what you are about to nuke from orbit.  C++ and Pascal language rules and concepts are less transferable to this environment than, say C#, where heap-object-lifetime and scare-resource-release are frequently decoupled.